# Visual Studio 2012 Qt4.8 mocing failes

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, qt4, mocking

I'm using Qt4.8 with Visual Studio 2012 with Qt VS add-in 1.1.8. And I have a problem with `moc_` files generation. If I add new class (with `.h` and `.cpp` files) to my project, where Q_OBJECT is supplied, then `moc_` file is not being generated correctly and I get linking errors.

In `.h` file's custom build tool's command line, `moc.exe`'s commands should be filled automatically. It seems everything is OK in Production configuration, but in Debug and Release configurations custom build tools command lines are empty and every time I have to write them, build and add `moc_` file to my project manually, which is  quite inconvenient.

So what can be problem for automatic generation? Which solution can be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Although I use CMake to generate the moc_ files I did not think there was an addon that supported VS2012 and Qt4.8 at the same time. For this reason I develop in VS2010 but build my software releases in VS2012.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19184

Comment: In my first comment I probably should have worded it "I use CMake to generate my Visual Studio project files. And that CMake has support for Qt so during the project file generation it adds the custom build steps to the VS project for me to generate the moc_ files"

Comment: @drescherjm, is there a way for using `CMake` only for automatic mocing and no more? I need to keep Visual Studio's project files and use VS's compiler.

Comment: No you can not do that with CMake.